# AVPlayer usage in a view that is not visible

Tags: uiviewcontroller, avplayer, avaudiosession

I am developing a music iOS application. Let me explain the scenario:

I have two view controllers in tabbar. 
`MusicListViewController` (1st tab of the tabbar)
`PlayerViewController` (2nd tab of the tabbar)

`MusicListViewCOntroller` loads list of music from server and shows in table view controller, and in `tableview` controller I can play music, that means send notification to `PlayerViewController` and `playerViewController` plays that music.

**Problem:**
I have to support enable/disable option in background play mode for that i have to set `AVAudioSession` active and category which works fine but if I go to `PlayerViewController` if I play music from `MusicListViewController` and doesn't go to `PlayerViewController` it doesn't plays the music in background.

Comment: are you creating a background thread?

Comment: I think problem is that most of the code in PlayerViewController is writtent in ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear which only executes when i go to the PlayerViewController. But when i send notification from MusicListViewController to PlayerViewController and doesn't go to player view it causes problems.

Comment: it's hard for me to know and tell you this or that, but if you want it to run in background, create a background thread....

Comment: @LiranElisha can you please tell me one thing, you have two views A and B, from A you send notification to B and from B's Method that receive notification you do some stuff, but in B there are further code in ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear how that code will be executed without going to B view controller.

Comment: if you won't share the code it's gonna be hard to talk about it....